# I'm using a popup for user login, how do i refresh the parent(openner) page when user actually logs in?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

The popup function is written in JQuery. It is placed on the parent page. When I click on a login button on the parent page, there will be a popup window asking for username and password. When the user actually logs in, as soon as the user closes the window, I want to refresh the parent page. If the user did not log in, he just opened the popup window and close, i want the parent page to remain as it is (do not refresh).

And the login function is written in PHP.

Here's the sample code I want to modify, thanks so much.

```
function() { 
    if (<?php echo $is_loggedin ?>) {

          document.location.reload(true);

      }
```

I used a picture instead of a button for the login function. This function resides on the popup page.

```
$(function(){

        $('#login_onclick').click(function(){
            $('#login_form').submit();
        });

    });
```

Comment: you could chain an always() or done() or fail() function to sumbit(), which closes any overlays and updates anything the submit() does not. $('#login_form').submit().always(otherFunc());

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

And bind that to the login submit of the child window.

So with jQuery, inside the child window, try:

```
$(function(){
    $('#login_onclick').click(function(){
        $('#login_form').submit();
        window.opener.location.reload(); // Sorry for the mongrel JS/jQuery mix.
    });
});
```

More information about the opener:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.opener

Comment: Thanks. I used a picture instead of a button for login. I updated my code above. How can I modify the script to use window.opener?

Comment: @led I've just edited my answer so try and see if this will work for you.

Comment: TypeError: window.opener is null. I get this error when i use the above code..any idea? Thanks @Stegrex

Comment: @led Hmmm, not really sure why. I tried this on Firefox, Chrome, and IE 10 (with compatibility mode on as well) and they all appeared to work (I'm also using jQuery version 2).

Answer (score 0):

Use this script on login popup page (inside login 'susses' )

```
<script> window.top.location.reload(); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just JavaScript does not do the trick. I tried..Thanks for all of your inputs.

I eventually got it working by using the AJAX method in JQuery. Please let me know if I can improve my method. Thanks again.

Write another login ajax call:

```
function user_settings(){

       $.ajax({
              async: false,
              dataType: 'json',
              type:'post',
              url: 'validation/login',

              success: function (j) {

                login = j.ok;
                if (login){
                location.reload();
                }
              }
       })
})
```

This function will be called when the popup window is closed.